# How to get magento 2 default route name list ? (Without third party route)

Tags: magento2, frontend, routing

I am creating custom module which redirect to login if third party module route id find.(frontend)

but i have issue how to identify the current route is default or third party route ?

**how to check current route is default or third party ?**

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some hint for this problem.

You can try by looking into class
**\Magento\Framework\App\Route\Config**
at file

```
vendor/magento/framework/App/Route/Config.php
```

the function **_getRoutes** of Magento2 will return list of route's info as below.

(You may have to extend a new class from this because the scope of function is **protected** )
[image]

Based on current route as a **frontName**, you can extract the **module info** of this route as modules. From that you can know whether this module belong to Magento 2 default route or not.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Please explain with running example.

Comment: My Question is how to identify the current page route is magento default route or Third party route ??